# How to make this object "training" as a singleton object

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to make training object as a singleton object because I want to make each training session all the application activities. After the one item in the list of training is clicked a session should start. Could you please help :)

```
final Cursor cursor = db.select("SELECT * FROM training");

    while (cursor. moveToNext()) {
        Training training = new Training();
        training.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor

                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_ID)));

        training.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_TITLE)));

        training.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DESCRIPTION)));

        training.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_DATE)));

        training.setLocation(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_LOCATION)));

        // Pass to the arraylist
        this.trainingArrayList.add(training);
    }
public ArrayList<Training> getTrainingArrayList() {

    return trainingArrayList;
}

public void setTrainingArrayList(ArrayList<Training> trainingArrayList) {
    this.trainingArrayList = trainingArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate class called Training or something and declare the following:

```
static Training train = null;
public static Training getInstance(){
    if(train == null){
        train = new Training();
    }
    return train;
}
```

And you can declare the `Training` object as

```
Training train = nameofclass.getInstance();
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the constructor private.

Comment: So how can I use that variable train to make a list view. As you can see I am using cursor and making a new Training there. 
I am sorry if this question sounds stupid because I am amature in Android.

Comment: what is this Training actually ?? You are using a cursor after your initial declaration so i guess it doesn't make a difference @user3099195

Comment: Actually Training is a class name. Using Cursor I make a new Training to make a listview of Training (Title). After listview is clicked a Training starts its session in whole application.

Comment: You should declare Training as a global variable then, like in the start of your application and declare it there.

Comment: Where and how can I do that :s

Comment: In the beginning of your class declaration. You seem to have accepted the answer ... was the issue solved ?

Comment: I have three trainings in my db. And in ht listview there are three items with a same name . I mean there should be different three titles but returns a same title.

Comment: How can I declare the same training object that I get from Training training = className.getinstance() in this class below
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{}. I think I have the problem here.